# Why does artifactory create a logical -cache repository for each remote repository?

Tags: artifactory

I'm using artifactory (OSS 5.1.3) as a general build dependency cache.  I've noticed that in the repository browser, for each remote repository there is a second entry with `-cache` appended.  ex: "jcenter" and "jcenter-cache".

The `-cache` entries are created automatically.  After I added a generic "gradle-distributions" repository to cache https://services.gradle.org/distributions/, I found that I had a "gradle-distributions-cache" repository in the tree as well.  The `-cache` has a different icon, but it's not listed under any of the different repository types in the admin area, and it's not selectable as a source when defining a virtual repository.

Once I've downloaded an artifact once, I can access it through either the main repository name or the `-cache` name.  But if I haven't downloaded something yet, then the `-cache` name will 404 (while the main name will go out and fetch it).

I couldn't find anything in the settings or documentation to explain the `-cache` repository.  It's useful as a way of seeing what artifactory has already downloaded from the remote, but is there another explanation for it that I'm not apprehending?  Is there a reason to point to one name or another in direct urls?  (ex: `gradle wrapper --gradle-version 3.4.1 --gradle-distribution-url http://localhost:8081/artifactory/gradle-distributions/gradle-3.4.1-bin.zip`)  This is mainly a curiosity question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "-cahce" repositories are mentioned in the [remote repositories](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Configuring+Repositories#ConfiguringRepositories-RemoteRepositories) configuration section.
The idea is that in some cases it is useful to directly access artifacts that are already stored in the cache (for example to avoid remote update checks).

Comment: I wonder why this is not transparent to the user. Users are usually not interested in cache design, they just want the content, fresh and fast...